# Meteor - How to display elapsed time since date

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm wanting to display the elapsed time since a specific Date, in this case, the record creation date returned from the DB.

The template simplified:

```
<template name="shiftduty">
   Uptime: {{uptime}}
</template>
```

The following only gets called once during page load, but I need to update every second. What's the most elegant way to handle this?

```
Template.shiftduty.onCreated(function () {
    Meteor.subscribe('shifts');
 });

Template.shiftduty.helpers({   
  'uptime': ()=>{
    var doc = Shifts.findOne({},{sort: {last_update:-1}});
    var mins = (new Date().getTime() - doc.create_date.getTime())/60000;
    return mins.toFixed(1) + ' mins ago';
 }
});
```

Do I again try `Meteor.setInterval` with `ReactiveVar`? I can't seem to get it together with those. I'm not so keen on filling global with the `Session.set/get` solutions that I've seen. Feels a bit crude to me.

Comment: a reactivevar and setinterval is a good way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ReactiveVar and SetInterval :-

> ```
>   Template.shiftduty.onCreated(function () {
>         Meteor.subscribe('shifts');    
>         this.uptime = new ReactiveVar();
>         Meteor.setInterval(() => {
>           var doc = Shifts.findOne({},{sort: {last_update:-1}});
>           var mins = (new Date().getTime() - doc.create_date.getTime())/60000;    
>           this.uptime.set(mins)
>         }, 1000);
>      });
>
>     Template.shiftduty.helpers({
>       uptime: () =>  Template.instance().uptime.get().toFixed(1) + " mins ago"
>     });
> ```

Comment: Really nice solution @keith.  I couldn't quite pull all that together but you've cracked it. Many Thanks.

Comment: It can also be done with remcoder/chronos: `uptime()=>Chronos.moment(dc.last_update).fromNow();`

Answer (score 0):

> This include momentjs and reactiveVar libs. I hope this will be
>   helpfull

```
Template.yourTemplate.onRendered(function() {
        Session.set('clock',0);
        self.handle = Meteor.setInterval((function() {
            var secunds = Session.get('clock');
            Session.set('clock',secunds+1);
        }), 1000);
    });



Template.yourTemplate.helpers(function() {
       uptime:function(){
          var doc = Shifts.findOne({},{sort: {last_update:-1}});
          if(doc){
               var date = new Date(doc.create_date).getTime();
               var currentDiff = moment().diff(date, 'seconds');
               var seconds = new ReactiveVar(currentDiff);
               var duration = seconds.get() + Session.get('clock');
               return duration;
          }
       }
 });

Template.yourTemplate.onDestroyed(function() {
    Meteor.clearInterval(this.handle);
});
```

and you can format like this: hh/mm

```
function durFormated(duration) {
    var h = duration/3600 ^ 0;
    var m = (duration-h*3600)/60 ^ 0;
    var s = duration-h*3600-m*60;
    return {h:(h<10?"0"+h:h), m:(m<10?"0"+m:m)};
}
```

Comment: why do you make a reactive var and throw it away??